# How to add route like example.com/module/controller/function/params in kohana

Tags: php, module, kohana

for example:

`/modules/test/controllers/index.php` - folder structure

`example.com/test/index/param1/someValue` - url

or something like this.

What I need to write in the bootstrap to make this path?

```
Route::set('test', 'test')
  ->defaults(array(
      'directory'  => 'modules/test/controllers',
      'controller' => 'index',
      'action'     => 'index',
  ));
```

But this does not  work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Kohana routing doc's a little lacking and wrote a very detailed overview that should answer your question: http://www.kineticklink.com/kohana-3-routing/

Note: I never got to the more advanced regular expression matching stuff--was going to be a part 3

Comment: so from that i read, its looks like i need to name my classes Controller_Modules_Test_Index - ??